# Создание сложного объекта

Tags: html, css

Добрый день,
сегодня столкнулся с такой задачей не могу сделать вот такой элемент
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
пробовал это сделать через так

```
position: relative;
z-index: 9;
transform: rotate(45deg);
width: 4.6875vw;
height: 4.6875vw;
background: #ffffff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 18px 18px 0px 0px rgba(255,156,0,1),  50px 50px 70px 10px rgba(0, 66, 103, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 18px 18px 0px 0px rgba(255,156,0,1),  50px 50px 70px 10px rgba(0, 66, 103, 0.75);
box-shadow: 18px 18px 0px 0px rgba(255,156,0,1),  50px 50px 70px 10px rgba(0, 66, 103, 0.75);
```

Но выходит не получается получить такой же эффект а именно у меня левый и праавый угол белого блока не прикасается к оранжевому цвету как показано на рисунке
Может кто то знает решение этой задачи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вроде бы похоже ...**

```css
   

.a {
  margin:100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 205px;
  background: #ccc;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  perspective: 200px;
  transform: rotateZ(30deg)rotateY(25deg);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 6px #777, 7px 17px 6px #777;
}

.a:after {
  content: "";
  width: 198px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 98%;
  left: 0;
  background: #777;
  transform: rotateX(-30deg);
}

.a:before {
  content: "";
  width: 160px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 41.5%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 20px solid #777;
  transform: rotateZ(90deg)rotateX(50deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```